# How many groups of order $125$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

What is the basic idea?

Normally for classification, I use Sylow theorem to use semidirect product, but since $125 = 5^3$, I cannot use it.

All I know is that $Z(G)$ cannot be identity and from the cauchy theorem I necessarily have subgroup of order $5$, but I don't seem to use these facts to figure out the ways to classify group of order $125.$

Comment: By the usual generalized statement of the Sylow theorems we also know that there is a subgroup of order $25$.

Comment: It's a textbook result that there are two non-Abelian groups of order $p^3$ up to isomorphism for each prime $p$.

Comment: The abelian case is easy. For the non-abelian case the result described by Lord Shark the Unknown is explained in [one of Keith Conrad's blurbs](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, how can I know there exists subgroup of order 25?

Comment: You can look at the order of elements: try to show that if the group is not abelian you cannot have all elements of order $1$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime number. Then there are, up to isomorphism, five groups of order $p^3$. These include three abelian groups and two non-abelian groups. The nature of the two non-abelian groups is somewhat different for the case $p = 2$.

The three abelian groups correspond to the three partitions of $3$.

The two non-abelian groups: For the case $p = 2$, these are dihedral group:$D_{8}$ and quaternion group. For the case of odd $p$, these are unitriangular matrix group:$UT(3,p)$ and semidirect product of cyclic group of prime-square order and cyclic group of prime order.